# Prove the cardinality of a set of rational numbers equal to base 11 set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have a base 11 set defined as follows,

$$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A\}^*$$

where the asterisk * means the set of all possible values made up of elements $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A\}$.

Now if we have a set of positive rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}^+$. Then, let us define a function $f$ mapping from $\mathbb{Q}^+$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A\}*$ as follows,

$$f(p/q)=pAq$$
$$gcd(p,q)=1$$

where $A$ is a digit corresponds to 10 in based 11 set.

We can show that $f$ is indeed one-to-one starting from $x=\frac{a}{b}$, $y=\frac{c}{d}$, with $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}^+$,

$$f(x)=f(y)$$
$$\cdots$$
$$a=c, b=d$$

thus $x=y$, which means $f$ is one to one.

**Question**: since $f: \mathbb{Q}^+ \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A\}^*$ is one-to-one, then how you can show that the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}^+$ or $\mid \mathbb{Q}^+ \mid$ is,

$$\mid \mathbb{Q}^+ \mid \le \mid \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A\}^* \mid$$

Comment: Isn't this immediate? Doesn't $|X|\leq |Y|$ mean that there is an injection $f:X\to Y$?

Comment: @TrevorNorton. Thank you. Can you please define what you mean by $\mid X \mid \le \mid Y \mid$?

Comment: By $|X|\leq |Y|$ I just mean that $X$ has a cardinality less than or equal to $Y$.

Comment: @TrevorNorton. So it does mean in English that the set of elements that in $X$ are less or equal to the set of elements in $Y$? What if we have only two elements in $X$ that are matched to one element in $Y$, then how the cardinality definition help us to identify that it's indeed one-to-one although $Y$ have 5 elements and $X$ has 2 elements?

Comment: It means that the "size" of the set $X$ is smaller than or equal to the "size" of the set $Y$. Do you mean that there is a one-to-one correspondence between elements in $X$ and $Y$ here (usually we say *functions* are one-to-one if they are injections)? To show that the cardinalities are the same using this definition you'd have to show both $|X|\leq |Y|$ and $|Y|\leq |X|$ (which gives $|X| = |Y|$). That is, you'd need to find $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ which are both injections. In the case above, you'd have $|X|\leq |Y|$ but you could not show the other direction.

Comment: @TrevorNorton. I am still a little confused as the only thing I have known so far about one-to-one functions is that if there is $f(a)=f(b)$  iff $a=b \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. I am still not sure how this is connected with the cardinality definition given above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121233/discussion-between-trevor-norton-and-avra).

Comment: Couple of questions. What base are $p$ and $q$ expressed in? (I'm guessing base 10 but you don't say). And why is there no zero in the base 11 set, if the expression of either $p$ or $q$ might contain that?

Comment: Follow-on thought: we could also show that the rationals are the same cardinality as the integers by expressing $p$ and $q$ in base 9 and separating with a $9$ (and of course every integer has a rational form).

Comment: @Joffan. Yes $p, q$ are in decimal representation, but $f(a) , f(b)$ are in base 11.

Comment: And about the zeros in $p,q$? for example $p=10,q=101$?

Comment: @Joffan. In the decimal representation, it can have any number $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. In the base 11, $A$ is added, which is same as $10$

Comment: Yeah, but for the $p,q$ I give, they don't fall in the defined set when put through $f()$, because the result has zeroes in it